# C fork not exiting

Tags: c, fork

I am fairly new to C and I wrote the code below to exec some shell script (nsdc.sh) every 10 seconds. For some reason it is calling the shell script many times (in a loop). It seems the `_exit` is not being called. Can anyone explain this behavior to me?

```
#include "dynzone.h"

void
dynzone_run(struct nsd *nsd)
{
    while(1) {
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if(pid == -1) {
            log_msg(LOG_ERR, "fork zone reload failed");
        } else if(pid == 0) {
            /* CHILD */
            log_msg(LOG_NOTICE, "exec reload");

            if(system("/home/edns/jarno/v1/nsdc.sh reload") == -1) {
                printf("reload error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            }

            _exit(1);
        }

        sleep(10);
    }
}

void
dynzone_spawn(struct nsd *nsd)
{
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();

    if(pid == -1) {
        log_msg(LOG_ERR, "fork dynzone failed");
    } else if(pid == 0) {
        /* CHILD */
        log_msg(LOG_NOTICE, "spawned dynzone");

        dynzone_run(nsd);

        /* ENOTREACH */
        exit(0);
    }

    /* PARENT */
    return;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this code seems to be fine can you gave us the full picture as it seems that some code has been cut out of the function since you have an unused param you could also want to debug the thing and see where and why the script is called gdb has the ability to do that...

Answer (score 1):

So, after usual deduction and trusting in all aspects of your description, there could be only one possible path of execution, which leads to your observed result:

Your "nsdc.sh" script will never exit at all.

Right?

Comment: Or it could blocked on something, Holmes.  In any case, check the script, OP>

Comment: @Duck: exactly! Jarno: Please note, that "system()" will return only after the specified command has executed. So... ensure, that your script will exit and not just idle.

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate some more. But still, if it is stuck on nsdc.sh not exiting, it still should not be spamming many instances of nsdc.sh, right?

Comment: @Jarno: Your code will still spawn a new child each 10 seconds, because of the "fork loop"...

Comment: Yes, but currently it is spawning nsdc.sh instances in a loop without any delay (hundreds per second).

Comment: @Jarno: note, that `sleep()` may not really wait all the 10 seconds, because it received a signal before... I am not 100% sure, but it may be possible, that your sleep returns hardly immediately because a SIG_CHILD is received...

Comment: I should have mentioned dynzone_run is also forked and thus a child from my main program. Could this have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: @Jarno: I don't think so. Check execution of nsdc.sh first.

Comment: nsdc.sh does send a reload signal and exits afterwards. It seems you are right about the `sleep()` returning hardly immediately. How to avoid this behavior?

Comment: This gets a bit complicated, you should read about process control in UNIX. However, `man sleep` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) is a good starting point ;-)

Comment: BTW: you could just determine the exact signal that disturbes your sleep calls, and just ignore this one. But you should better understand teh whole thing. So, that's why I suggest you to understand process control in a UNIX environment. Good luck.